# Select Column values in SQL to lines?

Tags: sql

I have a table in SQL

```
CustomerCode    CustomerName    CustomerAddress
C1                 Sam           Kerala
C3                 Tom           TamilNadu
C4                 Alex          Kerala
```

When I search customer code C1, I need to get result in one row as:

```
Sam,
Kerala
```

Please kindly help me, if it is possible

Comment: But your example shows two rows? Which DBMS do you use?

Comment: I showed how to display the value, I need this in one row like <br>in html

Comment: That's two rows..., or do you mean "select CustomerName || '<br>' || CustomerAddress from table"?

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. However you can make an SQL function or stored procedure to return the data as desired.

Comment: But still, Can we get value from function as i mentioned?

Comment: Sure. In an SQL function you can process the records and return them as desired. What's your RDBMS?

Comment: can u please help me in that sense?

Comment: You can find an example on how to make an Oracle function here http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions.php

Answer (score 0):

Use `union`

```
select CustomerName from `table` where customerCode ='C1'
union
select CustomerAddress from `table` where customerCode ='C1'
```

Or

```
select concat(concat(CustomerName, ','),CustomerAddress)  from `table` where customerCode ='C1'
```

Comment: He said he needs it in one row. Your SQL retrurns two rows.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the database you are using but you can generally use this:

```
SELECT CustomerName + ',<br>' + CustomerAddress
FROM YourTable
WHERE customerCode = 'C1'
```